# creating shipping address picker with google places?

Tags: api

I am using google places api as an address autocomplete/picker.

The api returns with routes highways and more instead of just real addresses with street, country, city, zip and street_number.

If I could get only addresses with street_number (and city, country, zip code)...as the autocomplete address should allow user to select address for shipping so it must be a specific building and to avoid confusion I rather user will enter all details of a building instead of a building name and stuff like that.

currently loading api with this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
```

Thanks, your help is much appreciated!